# datagrid expander + RowDetailsVisibilityChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a nested grid, that works fine when I click on a datagrid(using RowDetailsVisibilityChanged).
After that I inserted an expander,and now I am having problems putting it all together.The problem is that expander when expanded is calling a method that has (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e),and rowdetails has (object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e). My expander works with the expanding,but does not populate data in a nested grid.
Can I somehow call RowDetailsVisibilityChanged from a Expanded method?
The main problem is that I must define

```
DataGrid innerDataGrid = e.DetailsElement as DataGrid;
```

And I can't do that in the expanded method because I do not have DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs

Expanded and RowDetailsVisibilityChanged methods:

```
private void tabela_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid innerDataGrid = e.DetailsElement as DataGrid;
    string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
    string query = "SELECT StanjeTR.Firma, StanjeTR.NazFirme, StanjeTR.Konto, StanjeTR.NazivKonta, Sum(StanjeTR.Duguje) AS SDuguje, Sum(StanjeTR.Potrazuje) AS SPotrazuje, Sum(StanjeTR.Saldo) AS Stanje, StanjeTR.Valuta, Sum(StanjeTR.DevDuguje) AS DDuguje, Sum(StanjeTR.DevPotrazuje) AS DPotrazuje, Sum(StanjeTR.DevSaldo) AS StanjeDeviza FROM StanjeTR WHERE StanjeTr.Firma = @Firma GROUP BY StanjeTR.Firma, StanjeTR.NazFirme, StanjeTR.Konto, StanjeTR.NazivKonta, StanjeTR.Valuta ORDER BY StanjeTR.Firma, StanjeTR.Konto";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
    {
        //CmdString = "SELECT emp_id, fname, lname, hire_date FROM Employee";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Firma", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(izborID);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("StanjeTR");
        sda.Fill(dt);
        innerDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;     
    }
}

private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    for (var vis = sender as Visual; vis != null; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as Visual)
    {
        if (vis is DataGridRow)
        {
            var row = (DataGridRow)vis;
            row.DetailsVisibility = row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void Expander_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (var vis = sender as Visual; vis != null; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as Visual)
    {
        if (vis is DataGridRow)
        {
            var row = (DataGridRow)vis;
            row.DetailsVisibility = row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="tabela" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="tabela_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionChanged="tabela_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>

    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander Expanded="Expander_Expanded" Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>

    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>  
            <DataGrid Name="innerDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Konto" Binding="{Binding Konto}" Width="200" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Naziv Konta" Binding="{Binding NazivKonta}" Width="200" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="SDuguje" Binding="{Binding SDuguje}" Width="200" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="SPotrazuje" Binding="{Binding SPotrazuje}" Width="200" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Firma}" Width="50" Header="Firma"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NazFirme}" Width="200" Header="Naziv Firme"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SDuguje}" Width="200" Header="Duguje"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SPotrazuje}" Width="200" Header="Potrazuje"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Valuta}" Width="100" Header="Valuta"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DDuguje}" Width="200" Header="Dev Duguje"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DPotrazuje}" Width="200" Header="Dev Potrazuje"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding StanjeDeviza}" Width="*" Header="Stanje deviza"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
I added my expander as a DataGridTemplateColumn, and on expand and collapsed events for the expander I added Visibility attirbutes.